Zoom share screen, with audio from a different browser tab
I'd like to use Zoom to share my screen, showing one browser tab, while sharing audio from a separate browser tab.  How do I do this?
More specifically, I open one full-screen browser tab that shows an image I want to share via share screen.  I also have a separate browser tab open to Youtube, to play music.  I'd like Zoom's share screen to show the image/video from the first browser tab, while capturing the audio from the Youtube tab.
Unfortunately, what happens in practice is that Zoom won't do both at the same time.  It will share the image from the first browser tab (if I focus the first browser tab), or the audio from the second browser tab (if I focus it), but not both at the same time.  As soon as I switch to the first browser tab, Youtube pauses its playback.  I am on Mac OS X, with both the operating system and Zoom fully updated.  Yes, I have selected "Share Sound" when I begin sharing the screen.  I've tried selecting a single application window, and I've tried selecting "Share Desktop".  Neither works.
Is there a solution?
